# Pycharm on Mac autocomplete not working when pressing enter

Tags: pycharm, intellisense

Just installed pycharm, but autocomplete doesn't work. The popups overlap don't know if it's normal and pressing space/tab/enter doesn't work to insert the suggested code. Searched everywhere but didn't have the solution. I tried toggling power save mode but has not effect. Also pressing insert key on my keyboard has no effect.

[image]

pressing enter or any other keys don't insert the code. The only way to get rid of the popups is to click the 3 dots on the bottom right.

I have the latest community edition of Pycharm.
Thanks